Azure API Management requests with trailing slashes returns 307 Temporary Redirect error
In the Azure project I have my services that are hidden by Azure Api Management service. The idea is to route all the request via APIm, so all of them can be verified by policies it contains.
For example I have endpoint on my Service1:
POST api/users/{userId} 

that is updating user info.
We didn't change any APIm settings, just added additional policies to inbound section and endpoint works as expected.
But we've figured out that when we add trailing slash to the end of the endpoint on APIm:
POST api/users/{userId}/

it returns 307 Temporary Redirect error with the "pure" azure link to the service.
We expect it to either just ignore '/' in the end or return 404 error, but instead we expose vulnerable information.
Google proposes solution to add policy that will just remove '/' from the end of the url but I don't think it's a solution.
My question next is there a way to tell APIm to return 404 in all unexpected cases and use 307 error only when I add such functionality via policies?

can you specify what do you mean by such functionality? Also share your policy and requirement clearly in order to help you better

@IkhtesamAfrin to set up APIm not to redirect anything until I clearly specify it

@IkhtesamAfrin if create simple app service with simple request and put it under APIm - '/' in the end of the path will return 307 Temporary Redirect. My question is how to change default behavior of APIm to not return 307

Can you share some screenshots for the same

Are you creating this as new API in APIM or importing any Azure resource? @SoulCub
